# Do miners prefer RBF transactions over non-RBF transactions?

Tags: transaction-selection, replace-by-fee

Given a [replace-by-fee (RBF)](https://bitcoincore.org/en/faq/optin_rbf/) transaction and a non-RBF transaction with equal fees, do miners prefer the RBF transaction over the non-RBF one? Or is this entirely up to the particular miner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the miner, but typically they do not care whether it is RBF or not. There's no difference to the miner whether they choose one or the other; the miner still earns the same amount in transaction fees.