# Are non-RBF transactions more likely to be confirmed sooner?

Tags: replace-by-fee

Are non-RBF transactions more likely to be confirmed sooner?

It would seem miners would prefer them (*contra* [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/69534/4334)) because they don't have to worry about another miner utilizing a higher fee re-send of the TXN.

Answer (score 1):

> Are non-RBF transactions more likely to be confirmed sooner?

No.

> because they don't have to worry about another miner utilizing a higher fee re-send of the TXN.

Why would that be a concern? If another miner finds a block first, the miner in question won't make anything at all, whether the transaction gets replaced or not. Miners optimize for their own income they will get *assuming* they win the block. Nothing else is within their control.

And to optimize for that, they try to construct blocks that maximize their fee income - whether that's from RBF or non-RBF transactions is irrelevant for them.

Comment: "_Why would that be a concern?_" What's meant by the Bitcoin Core popup hovering over "Enable Replace-By-Fee": "Without this, a higher fee may be recommended to compensate for increased transaction delay risk."? What is transaction delay risk?

Comment: @Geremia With RBF enabled you can increase the fee of a transaction at any time, so you can get away with initially setting it low. Without RBF, you have to get the fee right the first time around and so you better set it high enough, that's what the popup warns you about.